# Swift, XCode6: Adding and deleting new sections in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to create a view which has a button at the top and a uitableview right beneath it. The uitableview has a section of 3 rows by default. What I wish to achieve is that whenever the button is pressed, I wish to add a new section of 4 rows. The first row of every newly added section should delete the section on selection. Sections are appended to the bottom of the existing sections as the top button is pressed. However, they can be deleted from the middle.

I have posted my code below. Sections are being added fine. However, deletion is not happening properly. If I select the 0th row of a newly added section, nothing happens. But if I select the 0th row and then select the 1st row of the same section, the section gets deleted. I am also not sure about my add new section logic. I am new to iOS development, please help me in getting this right, thanks in advance!

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var retailProduct: RetailProduct?

let mandatoryVariants = 1

var additionalVariants = 0


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            var variantImagesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("variantImagesCell") as! VariantImagesCell
            cell = variantImagesCell
            break
        case 1:
            var variantColorCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addColorCell") as! AddColorCell
            variantColorCell.colorLabel.text = "Color"
            if let color = retailProduct?.colorVariants[0].color {
                variantColorCell.colorName.text = color.description
            } else {
                variantColorCell.colorName.text = "Select Color"
            }
            cell = variantColorCell
            break
        case 2:
            var variantQuantityCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addQuantityCell") as! AddQuantityCell
            variantQuantityCell.addQuantityLabel.text = "Size and Quantity"
            variantQuantityCell.quantity.text = String(0)
            cell = variantQuantityCell
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    } else {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            var deleteVariantCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("deleteCell") as! DeleteCell
            cell = deleteVariantCell
            break
        case 1:
            var variantImagesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("variantImagesCell") as! VariantImagesCell
            cell = variantImagesCell
            break
        case 2:
            var variantColorCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addColorCell") as! AddColorCell
            variantColorCell.colorLabel.text = "Color"
            if let color = retailProduct?.colorVariants[0].color {
                variantColorCell.colorName.text = color.description
            } else {
                variantColorCell.colorName.text = "Select Color"
            }
            cell = variantColorCell
            break
        case 3:
            var variantQuantityCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addQuantityCell") as! AddQuantityCell
            variantQuantityCell.addQuantityLabel.text = "Size and Quantity"
            variantQuantityCell.quantity.text = String(0)
            cell = variantQuantityCell
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    //println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ " + String(indexPath.section) + " " + String(indexPath.row))
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ " + String(indexPath.section) + " " + String(indexPath.row))
    if (indexPath.section > 0) && (indexPath.row == 0) {
        additionalVariants--
        let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
        indexSet.addIndex(indexPath.section)
        self.tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
@IBAction func addColorVariants(sender: AnyObject) {
    additionalVariants++
    let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
    indexSet.addIndex(additionalVariants)
    //self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(1, 5)), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    //self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    //self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You implemented `didDeselect` instead of `didSelect`

Comment: It worked! Such a silly mistake! Thanks a ton @dan!